# Make exe or bat require admin privileges UAC

Tags: windows, uac

I am trying to create an install CD to install multiple windows updates and hotfixes in one. The Autorun.inf launching a .bat (or .exe) running each update in turn. Currently if I run this .bat each update brings up a UAC prompt individually which can be annoying.

However if I run the .bat as administrator it can launch and install each update with just one prompt.

Is there a way to force the bat (or .exe) to need admin priviledges no matter who runs it.

Answer (score 1):

For a normal executable you should just change the manifest to tell the OS that this application requires administrative privileges. This isn't possible with batch files, at least not in the normal way. You can use `runas` but this won't trigger the UAC prompt and therefore is probably not too nice from a UX point of view.

So the best way would probably be to use a helper application correctly configured to require administrative privileges which does the work of the batch file.

Comment: runas will not work if the Admin approval mode is turned off, which is by default on Domain joined machines.